# How to create a class with lots of attributes without code duplication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have the following class for representing a news alert

```
class Incident:
    news_id: Optional[str] = None
    created_at: str
    service: str
    status: str
    title: str
    content: str
     category: Optional[str] = None
    news_url: Optional[str] = None
    updated_at: Optional[str] = None
    published_at: Optional[str] = None
    city: Optional[str] = None
    state: Optional[str] = None
    ....
     def __init__(self,
                 status: str, service: str, created_at: str, title: str, content: str, news_id: Optional[str] = None,
                 category: Optional[str] = None, news_url: Optional[str] = None, updated_at: Optional[str] = None,
                 published_at: Optional[str] = None, city: Optional[str] = None, state: Optional[str] = None,
                 country: Optional[str] = None, address: Optional[str] = None, region: Optional[str] = None,
                 latitude: Optional[float] = None, longitude: Optional[float] = None,
                 images: Optional[List[Dict[str, str]]] = None):
        self.news_id = news_id
        self.status = status
        self.category = category
        self.service = service
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.news_url = news_url
        self.created_at = created_at
        self.updated_at = updated_at
        self.published_at = published_at
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.country = country
        self.address = address
        self.region = region
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.images = images
```

I think whole class looks ugly. Attributes are listed three times.

I'm new in python and wondering is there any way to organize it more clearly? Maybe with dataclasses.

Comment: Why did you add them on class level as well?

Comment: @KlausD. could you explain please in which case we should add attributes on a class level as well?

Comment: if you define them on a class level - they'll be the same across all instances

Comment: You should not. Except there is some framework magic involved (example: Django models). But then you don't add instance variables.

Comment: why not to use an ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)


test = Test(a=1, b=2)
print(test.a)
print(test.b)
```

However, I would re-think the whole class structure. Classes are not just dicts, the attributes are meant to be used somewhere. If they are not, they are just a data structure. If they are, you should probably group subsets of those arguments into other classes.